# SSH server on virtualbox ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

I am new to SSH and have a few questions regarding connecting to it.
So i was recently given access to the gpu server in the university and was wondering how to utilize it to speed up my reinforcement learning training, i mainly uses pytorch with openai gym environment and also stable baselines.

Before all this, i was running ubuntu on virtualbox with all my dependencies downloaded on conda environments in the VM, however when i connect to the SSH server i can no longer access the files and conda env. Which i later learnt was because i was using the filesystem in the server that i connected to.
Would it possible to utilize the gpu server while accessing my local file systems or would it better to re-install the conda environment inside the gpu server? Also with regards to the python scripts and environments such as mujoco, do i have to install it again it the server?

The reason why i use ubuntu was because i had issues with intalling mujoco using windows OS. I was only able to do so using linux OS, so if i can do away with using virtualbox and just connect to the GPU server and access the mujoco environments, that would be better as using virtualbox is kind of laggy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GPU Server usually had set conda environment.
Just conda configure your python version environment and active it.
like：
`conda create --name python34 python=3.4`
`source activate python34`  to use your Python environment.
or
`source deactivate python34`  when quit.